# Roslyn Declare Local Variable with SyntaxGenerator

Tags: c#, roslyn

I am attempting to write a compiler for a proprietary language based off of C/C++/C#, but with the more complex features hidden. The compiler uses ANTLR to build it's own syntax tree, then uses the Roslyn `SyntaxGenerator` class to build the code in C#, which is then compiled as usual for C# code. My current issue is handling variables inside of functions: as it's fairly simple to declare a field, local variables don't seem to be discussed or clear to create. How do I create a local variable with the `SyntaxGenerator` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `SyntaxGenerator.LocalDeclarationStatement`.

For example, if you have initialized expression you can use it like this:

```
SyntaxGenerator generator = ...;
generator.LocalDeclarationStatement(
    "variable",
    generator.LiteralExpression(1));
```

This will create statement `var variable = 1;`.

Or if you just want to create variable but assign it later:

```
SyntaxGenerator generator = ...;     
generator.LocalDeclarationStatement(
    generator.TypeExpression(SpecialType.System_Int32),
    "variable");
```

This will generate statement `int variable;`.